# Mobile Redirect using Resolution

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, asp.net

I have 2 page index.php (For Desktop) and indexm.php (For Mobile). I want to redirect it with detection of screen resolution size. I'm trying this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width <= 720) {
        window.location = "indexm.php";
    } else {
        window.location = "index.php";
    }
</script>
```

and i am trying same in PHP,

```
<?php 
  if (screen.width <= 720) {
      include "indexm.php";
  } else {
      include "index.php";
  }
?>
```

But both the code is not working, Please help me with PHP or JavaScript code to make it work.

Comment: How are you testing it? during initial load or while resizing?

Comment: what is screen here ... ?

Comment: @brk Initial load

Comment: @NegiRox Screen size can be any and it differ but normally we know desktop screen is big and mobile is always less then 800 so in this logic, i am placing to change the index page for mobile user and desktop user.

Comment: according to it should work properly using javascript.

Comment: @NegiRox I see it working in JS after small changes but still PHP one is not working. Do you have any solution for PHP?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, it knows nothing about the screen resolution of the client, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming - and you can't just stick `<?php ... ?>` around some JavaScript code; it's a completely different language. You'd probably be better off just creating a responsive design with CSS anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript:

change `window.location` to `window.location.href = ('indexm.php');`

For php I think using header is the best:

```
header('Location: indexm.php');
```

Comment: Can you help me with `Include` instead of `Header location` in PHP?

Comment: Php does not have screen.width instead use get_browser(); and loop through the array.

Comment: I'm not PHP expert and still learning? Can you please tell how to do that?

Comment: Using this method is not sure it will always for all phones and browsers.

Comment: Try using JavaScript and log `screen` to the `console` before the if statements.